# Using AxInterop.MSWinsockLib for socket programming's state stays at 6-Connecting

Tags: vb.net, sockets, activex

I am using AxInterop.MSWinsockLib.dll together with Interop.MSWinsockLib.dll and MSWINSCK.OCX to create a socket connection to a printer. The following code is what I use but no matter if I put the code inside a while loop or Thread.Sleep() after the attempt to connect, The connection state still remains at 6, which is "Connecting". Please assist ASAP.

```
        Try
        Dim sock As AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock
        sock = New AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock
        CType(sock, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.Controls.Add(sock)
        CType(sock, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        sock.RemoteHost = "10.194.1.132"
        sock.RemotePort = 3001
        sock.Connect()
        MessageBox.Show(sock.CtlState.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: There are some VB6 controls that deserve retirement in a nice warm place sipping pina coladas.  MSWinsock is on the top of the list, don't expect it to work in a console mode app or service.  Use the .NET TcpClient class instead.  Use SysInternals' TcpView utility to get basic diagnostics.  Ensure the port is opened on your firewall.  Ensure the printer actually listens on that port.

Comment: Lol I hear you... Unfortunately, I have to use it due to old code.